# Filebodyparser with input text field in play2

Tags: forms, file-upload, playframework-2.3, loops

I am using Bootstrap tagsinput to annotate my file with tags:

```
@helper.form(action=routes.Upload.save(projectId), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data" ) 
{   
    <input type="file" name="corpus">   
    <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo"  name="tags" id="tags" data-role="tagsinput"/>
    <input type="submit">
}
```

In the controller, I am trying to bind the request to the form:

```
  def save(id:Long) = Action(requestCsvBodyParser){ implicit request =>
    uploadForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      hasErrors => {
        BadRequest
      },
      success = { formData =>
        // accessing formData.tags
        // parsing request.body and store in the database with tags
        Ok("Got request")
      }
    )
  }
```

requestCsvBodyParser is an Iteratee[Array[Byte], List[String]]. As far as I know, the file should not be part of the validation form, so I defined my form as follows:

```
  private val uploadForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "tags" -> list(text)
    )(UploadTags.apply)(UploadTags.unapply)
  )
```

which results in a successful request, but with empty `tags`. If I use a `text` instead of `list(text)` then I always end up with an `BadRequest`.

I am also not shure if it is the **reactive way** of parsing, when I do it within the form validation.

edit (add Bodyparser)
BodyParser:

```
 /** Enumeratee that transforms a stream of Array[Byte] into a stream of Byte */
  val toBytes: Enumeratee[Array[Byte], Byte] = Enumeratee.mapInputFlatten[Array[Byte]] {
    case Input.El(arr) => Enumerator[Byte](arr: _*)
    case Input.Empty => Enumerator.empty[Byte]
    case Input.EOF => Enumerator.eof[Byte]
  }

  val concatLine: Iteratee[Parsing.MatchInfo[Array[Byte]],String] =
    ( Enumeratee.breakE[Parsing.MatchInfo[Array[Byte]]](_.isMatch) ><>
      Enumeratee.collect{
        case Parsing.Unmatched(bytes) => new String(bytes)
      } &>>
      Iteratee.consume() ).flatMap(r => Iteratee.head.map(_ => r))

  val txtToParagraph: Iteratee[Array[Byte], List[String]] =
    Parsing.search("\r\n\r\n".getBytes) ><>
      Enumeratee.grouped( concatLine ) &>>
      Iteratee.head.flatMap( header => Iteratee.getChunks.map(header.toList ++ _) )


  val requestCsvBodyParser = BodyParser(rh => txtToParagraph.map(Right(_)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a form value to be parsed as a list you need to add an index to the input name, e.g: `tags[0]`, `tags[1]`, or just append `[]` as outlined in the [2.4.x form docs section on repeated values](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms#Repeated-values).

On the other hand, if you want a single text field accepting comma-delimited values which are to end up as a list, then you could transform them like so:

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._

case class UploadTags(
  tags: List[String]                  
)

object UploadTags {
  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "tags" -> text.transform[List[String]](
        str => str.split(",").map(_.trim).toList,
        list => list.mkString(",")
      )
    )(UploadTags.apply)(UploadTags.unapply)
  )
}
```

i.e. provide a function to pack and unpack the values into that single form field.

Correct that the file upload should/can be validated separately.

Comment: your parsing works fine, but the problem arises when I add the requestCsvBodyParser. I've added my Bodyparser.